# sample size/ clinical trail

Tags: statistical-power, small-sample

I was reading a paper that used a clinical trial method to look at the efficacy of a drug to prevent TB. The exposed group was compared to a placebo group.

The problem is that each group was made up of only 1000 people, while the TB rate of infection is ~ $\frac{70 \text{ infections}}{100,000 \text{ people}}$. My guess is many more subjects are needed. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Depends. The trial protocol may do a good job of ensuring that high risk patients are enrolled so that amongst trial participants the rate is much higher. Additionally, the observation period will also matter (with some exposure to risk of infection there should be some extra risk for every extra day a person is observed for).

With sufficiently high risk patients observed for long enough, a much higher proportion of patients may get an event and then the sample size could well  be fine. The trial protocol would have a section explaining why the sample size is appropriate that would give details on this.